# Android: fill_parent and wrap_content do not fill full screen on all devices

Tags: android, size, screen

Ok, i understand all the higher density phones and screens and all that, my problem is why does my background color not fill the entire page? on my tablet it is just a small box of the background color and the rest is just a block background. please help.

BONUS QUESTION: For the higher density phones, does that mean i have to make 3 different images and then put them in the different folders or can i just make 1 image and place them in the folder and then the app will take care of everything else? Really i dont understand exactly if i control my image quality/resolution and the app chooses which one, or if the app will auto change the images to the proper resolution and size.

Activity file:

```
package u.nav.it;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;

public class UNavitActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_title);
    }
}
```

custom_title.xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#62CFD2"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/selectiontitle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

     <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#323331</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="u.nav.it"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".UNavitActivity" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but, shouldn't you be implementing an Action Bar instead of a "custom title"? You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to support most devices.

Comment: Well the title bar is simply always going to just be text (well really an image of the text), i don't plan on having any buttons or anything like that. It is just suppose to stay that color and then the text may will change. So would an action bar really be necessary?

Comment: What is the minimum/target sdk declared in your manifest?

Comment: I dont have one, it was defaulted to 15 but i always got a parsing error when trying to install when i had that so i deleted it and it worked fine.

Comment: Well it's not "necessary" of course, but it's the new standard, and if you're just starting might as well do it right. Especially if you're going to have a "title bar" of sorts anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to add in my manifest the screen sizes that the app supported. How i feel dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Try using draw9patch image to help expand the unfilled space

Comment: would that only expand my header image? does that affect the background of the entire app? when i set android:background="color" in my main.xml why would that not set the entire screen for any size to that color?